# C# form builder using JavaScript (onblur) to replace double quotes - conflict with 2 double quotes within single quotes

Tags: c#, javascript, replace, onblur, double-quotes

I'm modifying a custom form builder app written in C# by adding onblur to replace problematic characters like `<>` `/\` and hopefully `"` . I can get all replaces to work except for the double quotes due to my 2 double quotes issue. Can anyone help me get this to work? 
Here's a bit of my code:

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format(@"   
... lots of html ...
<input name=""txtTextLabel"" id=""txtTextLabel"" type=""text"" onblur=""this.value = this.value.replace('<', '[').replace('>', ']').replace('double quotes', '');""/>
... lots more html ...
"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for me:

```
<input name="txtTextLabel" id="txtTextLabel" type="text" 
onblur='this.value = this.value.replace("<", "[").replace(">", "]").replace("\"", "");'/>
```

I've put a \ before the double quote because that's how you escape the double quote in Javascript.

Note that in the onblur attribute I've reversed your usage of the single and double quote in order for it to work.

Also I realise that in your code you're replacing < with [ and > with ]

Comment: I was hoping that this would be possible without changing the double double quotes ("") as there would be a ton of code for me change. Am I to understand that what I am trying to do is not possible with the double double quotes?

Comment: Ah okay, I've actually found a way to do that. If you use your code and replace where you put the words double quotes with &quot; and this will escape the quote in the html. Hope that helps.

Comment: &quot; works! I can't believe I didn't try that first. Thanks!